# Как заменить значения одной переменной значениями других?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, pandas

Дан набор данных с целевой переменной`pglabgro`. Список значения переменных приведён ниже:

`pglabgro (=pglabgro)` - Текущий валовой доход в евро
`emp_full` - полная занятость (бинарная переменная)
`emp_not` - безработный (бинарная переменная)
`i11103` - трудовой доход домашнего хозяйства
`ijob1` - доход от основной работы
`ijob2` - Доходы от вторичной занятости

Данные выглядят следующим образом:

```
IncomeSet[IncomeSet["pglabgro"]<0].head()
Out[32]: 
            pid  syear     cid     hid  pglabgro  emp_full  emp_part  emp_not  \
330416  2585401   2006  258547  258547        -2         0         0        1   
330425   492301   2006   49239   49239        -2         0         0        1   
330428  3069801   2006  306983  306983        -2         0         0        1   
330429  2684101   2006  268410  268410        -2         0         0        1   
330432  3038501   2006  303852  303852        -2         0         0        1   

        i11103  ijob1  ijob2  plc0013                              
330416       0      0      0       -2  
330425     720      0      0       -2  
330428       0      0      0       -2  
330429       0      0      0       -2  
330432    9396   9396      0       -2
```

Значение переменной -2 означает что ответ на вопрос: "какой ваш текущий валковый доход?", не был дан. И отсутствие данных по этой переменной `pglabgro` характерно для тех людей кто не имеет работы (emp_not=1). Но таких значений очень много и при этом у некоторых людей всё же имеются доходы от основной или вторичной работы или доход домохозяйства `(i11103, ijob1, ijob2)`.

Поэтому хотелось бы сократить количество отсутствующих данных путем присвоения значений для переменной `pglabgro` из переменных `i11103`, `ijob1` и `ijob2`.

Для этого я написал следующую функцию:

```
for x in list(IncomeSet["pglabgro"]):
    if IncomeSet[IncomeSet["pglabgro"].ix[x]<0]:
        if IncomeSet[IncomeSet["i11103"]>=0 & IncomeSet["i11103"]]<=0:
            if IncomeSet[IncomeSet["ijob1"]>=0 & IncomeSet["ijob1"]]<=0:
                if IncomeSet[IncomeSet["ijob2"]>=0 & IncomeSet["ijob2"]]<=0:
                    IncomeSet["pglabgro"].ix[x]=-2
                else: 
                    IncomeSet["pglabgro"].ix[x]==IncomeSet["ijob2"]
            else:
                    IncomeSet["pglabgro"].ix[x]==IncomeSet["ijob1"]
        else:
                IncomeSet["pglabgro"].ix[x]==IncomeSet["i11103"]
    else:
            IncomeSet["pglabgro"].ix[x]==IncomeSet["pglabgro"]
```

Но я получаю ошибку: `KeyError: 400`
И пока не знаю как улучшить логику присвоения.

Результат согласно приведённому выше образцу данных должен выглядить следующим образом:

```
                pid  syear     cid     hid  pglabgro  emp_full  emp_part  emp_not  \
    330416  2585401   2006  258547  258547        -2         0         0        1   
    330425   492301   2006   49239   49239       720         0         0        1   
    330428  3069801   2006  306983  306983        -2         0         0        1   
    330429  2684101   2006  268410  268410        -2         0         0        1   
    330432  3038501   2006  303852  303852      9396         0         0        1   

        i11103  ijob1  ijob2  plc0013                              
330416       0      0      0       -2  
330425     720      0      0       -2  
330428       0      0      0       -2  
330429       0      0      0       -2  
330432    9396   9396      0       -2
```

Логика была такой:
Если значение переменной pglabgro из списка значений этой переменной равно -2, то мы смотрим на значение переменной дохода домохозяйства - i11103. Если Она отлична от нуля, то берём её значение, если нет, то переходим к переменной ijob1 (доход от основной работы). Если эта переменная отлична от нуля то присваиваем переменной pglabgro её значение, если она равна нулю, то переходим к последней переменной ijob2 (Доходы от вторичной занятости), если она равна нулю, то переменная pglabgro остаётся со значением -2. Если ijob2 > 0, то присваиваем её значение переменной pglabgro.

Таким образом для pglabgro мы заменяем значения -2 в соответствии с имеющимися значениями переменных i11103, ijob1 и ijob2.

Как заменить значения одной переменной значениями других?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина ошибки в неверном использовании `.ix[]` метода. Вот реконструкция вашей ошибки для приведенного вами примера:

```
In [22]: IncomeSet
Out[22]:
            pid  syear     cid     hid  pglabgro  emp_full  emp_part  emp_not  i11103  ijob1  ijob2  plc0013
330416  2585401   2006  258547  258547        -2         0         0        1       0      0      0       -2
330425   492301   2006   49239   49239        -2         0         0        1     720      0      0       -2
330428  3069801   2006  306983  306983        -2         0         0        1       0      0      0       -2
330429  2684101   2006  268410  268410        -2         0         0        1       0      0      0       -2
330432  3038501   2006  303852  303852        -2         0         0        1    9396   9396      0       -2

In [23]: list(IncomeSet["pglabgro"])
Out[23]: [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2]

In [24]: x = -2

In [25]: IncomeSet["pglabgro"].ix[x]
... skipped ...
KeyError: -2
```

В вашем случае в первой строке значение`pglabgro == 400`, поэтому возникает ошибка: `KeyError: 400`

Я бы заменил весь ваш `for x in list(IncomeSet["pglabgro"])` цикл на след. три строки:

```
In [60]: IncomeSet.ix[IncomeSet.eval('pglabgro == -2 and ijob1 > 0'), 'pglabgro'] = IncomeSet.ijob1

In [62]: IncomeSet.ix[IncomeSet.eval('pglabgro == -2 and ijob2 > 0'), 'pglabgro'] = IncomeSet.ijob2

In [63]: IncomeSet.ix[IncomeSet.eval('pglabgro == -2 and i11103 > 0'), 'pglabgro'] = IncomeSet.i11103
```

Результат:

```
In [64]: IncomeSet
Out[64]:
              pid   syear       cid       hid  pglabgro  emp_full  emp_part  emp_not  i11103   ijob1  ijob2  plc0013
330416  2585401.0  2006.0  258547.0  258547.0      -2.0       0.0       0.0      1.0     0.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330425   492301.0  2006.0   49239.0   49239.0     720.0       0.0       0.0      1.0   720.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330428  3069801.0  2006.0  306983.0  306983.0      -2.0       0.0       0.0      1.0     0.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330429  2684101.0  2006.0  268410.0  268410.0      -2.0       0.0       0.0      1.0     0.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330432  3038501.0  2006.0  303852.0  303852.0    9396.0       0.0       0.0      1.0  9396.0  9396.0    0.0     -2.0
```

Некоторые пояснения:

```
In [66]: IncomeSet.eval('pglabgro == -2 and ijob1 > 0')
Out[66]:
330416    False
330425    False
330428    False
330429    False
330432     True
dtype: bool

In [69]: IncomeSet.ix[IncomeSet.eval('pglabgro == -2 and ijob1 > 0'), 'pglabgro'] = IncomeSet.ijob1
```

после первого присвоения:

```
In [70]: IncomeSet
Out[70]:
              pid   syear       cid       hid  pglabgro  emp_full  emp_part  emp_not  i11103   ijob1  ijob2  plc0013
330416  2585401.0  2006.0  258547.0  258547.0      -2.0       0.0       0.0      1.0     0.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330425   492301.0  2006.0   49239.0   49239.0      -2.0       0.0       0.0      1.0   720.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330428  3069801.0  2006.0  306983.0  306983.0      -2.0       0.0       0.0      1.0     0.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330429  2684101.0  2006.0  268410.0  268410.0      -2.0       0.0       0.0      1.0     0.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0
330432  3038501.0  2006.0  303852.0  303852.0    9396.0       0.0       0.0      1.0  9396.0  9396.0    0.0     -2.0

In [71]: IncomeSet.eval('pglabgro == -2 and i11103 > 0')
Out[71]:
330416    False
330425     True
330428    False
330429    False
330432    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Как например для индекса 330432 имеются значения сразу для двух переменных i11103 и  ijob1? Я думал что последовательный перебор условий сможет как то справиться. Я просматриваю данные и для некоторых последних значений (параметр tail()) есть много NAN значений. Поэтому в первую очередь я считаю правильным было бы взять данные из колонки ijob1, если данные в ней равны нулю то, обратиться к ijob2, и если эта переменная тоже равна 0 то взять данные из i11103 , если в последней NAN или 0, то оставить -2 для pglabgro.

Comment: Это действительно, очень изящный способ. Как я понял из документации, пайтон оценивает `'pglabgro == -2 and ijob1 > 0'` это выражение в формате string как логическое, для переменной `pglabgro`. Возможно ли это заменить такой же функцией только используя логические операторы? (я не совсем понимаю как эта функция работает) Если я понимаю правильно, то логика такая, взять строку для которой `'pglabgro == -2 and ijob1 > 0'` верно и присвоить значение `= IncomeSet.ijob1`, верно? А зачем нужен параметр `'pglabgro'` после запятой? Спасибо Вам

Comment: @user21, не совсем понял вопрос... `x.eval('c1 == -2 and c2 > 0')` эквивалентно (и будет транслировано в): `(x.c1 == -2) & (x.c2 > 0)`